# Having Issues Accessing Controls within BIOS

Tags: bios, dell-inspiron

Once I get into my BIOS, I can't seem to go over to the other options or even use the commands to exit out of it. I have to physically turn off my computer because none of the commands within the BIOS work once I Access it. Somebody Please Help. Ive been looking everywhere for answers but have not found anything yet. I have a Inspiron 5675 On BIOS Version 1.3.7 (Latest Version).

Comment: are you trying to move around with the mouse or the keyboard?

Comment: Keyboard. I've Tried using the arrow keys and even the ESC button to exit the BIOS does not work.

Comment: Do you have any lights on your keyboard while you're in BIOS (i.e. can you make num lock or anything else light up?) Also, is your keyboard connected directly to your computer via USB?

Comment: My keyboard does seem to be on with all the lights inside BIOS. I can't turn off and on my NUM Lock inside BIOS though. My Keyboard is directly connected to my PC via 2 different USBs

Comment: I would try moving to different USB ports first (preferably in a different location on your tower if you have any available) - or if you have access to a keyboard with only one USB connection (i.e. something simpler) I would give that a shot as well. If the lights are on it's clearly getting power, but if BIOS isn't recognizing input it's likely the USB connections that are causing you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest based on the only information you've provided in your question. That it doesn't *like* your keyboard/protocol.

- If you're using a Bluetooth keyboard. Don't. Use a *corded* (`USB`) keyboard.
- If your corded `USB` keyboard doesn't work

a) Use a *different* keyboard

or

b) Use a different `USB` port

In *any* case. Ensure that there is NO other `USB` device attached to the `USB` port you're connecting the keyboard to.

Lastly, it may well be advisable to `RESET` the `BIOS`. I've read the manual [provided by Dell](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/inspiron-5675-gaming-desktop_owners-manual_en-us.pdf) for your Board, and it appears to be a 6 pronged shunt. You'll need to read the manual for the exact procedure. As I could not do the procedure justice here.

OH and speaking of the manual; I didn't notice that there was a `PS/2` port available. *If*, however there *is* a `PS/2` port. Use *that* for setting the `BIOS` options.